# I tried sy.worker(name) with syft 0.5.1

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I am working on multiparty computation with homomorphic encryption. Syft 0.5.1 doesn't have torchhook or virtualworker. I tried sy.worker('name') instead of sy.virtualworker(hook,ID) it worked, but I haven't figured out what to use instead of .send() and .get() to avoid the error 'Tensor' doesn't have the attribute of 'send' or 'get' to be able to link the users to the dataset. Any help? or any other way to link users to dataset.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.